# Analytic formula of definite integral of $exp(-\frac{x^2}{2(a+x)})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am looking for definite integral of $exp(-\frac{x^2}{2(a+x)})$ from 0 to $\infty$ where a is some positive constant, however, Wolfram Alpha seems to be unable to calculate it, and I don't know why because I can certainly find some upper bound of this function which is also integrable. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: I tried to graph $y=$ the integral on geogebra, it seems to have a well defined value for a>=0 but for a<0, the integral seems to jump to infinity at some points, while the integral being undefined for some values ...... https://www.geogebra.org/classic/u4eh9368.......  why would that be???

Comment: Assuming $a > 0$, I doubt that the given integral has a closed form expression in terms of $a$. One can obtain good approximations or upper bounds of the integral in terms of $a$ if that helps you.